# How to set date of birth in an android form without datepicker control

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am working on a project which has a sign up form where there is a field for date of birth.So i tried using datepicker control .But it was hard setting the maximum and minimum dates in the control .Also versions prior to honeycomb work differently from versions after honeycomb.The following is the code i used.

The main class:

```
package com.example.datepickercustom;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btndate;
TextView txtdate;
private int intCurrentYear;
private int intCurrentMonth;
private int intCurrentDay;
private int intMaxYear;
private int intMaxMonth;
private int intMaxDay;
private int intMinYear;
private int intMinDay;
private int intMinMonth;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private static final int MILLIS_IN_SECOND = 1000;
private static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
private static final int MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
private static final int HOURS_IN_DAY = 24;
private static final int DAYS_IN_YEAR = 365;
static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 
GregorianCalendar calendar;
DatePicker mDatePickerInstance;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange datePickerDialog= null;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerOnDateSetListener;
Calendar myCalendar;
DatePickerDialog dpd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btndate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btndate);
        txtdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {




        // Show current date

        txtdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));
        }
        else
        {

            setDate();
        }
        btndate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
                }
                else
                {
                datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
             final long MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR =
                (long)MILLIS_IN_SECOND * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * MINUTES_IN_HOUR
                * HOURS_IN_DAY * DAYS_IN_YEAR;
             Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
             calendar=new GregorianCalendar();
             int current_year=now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            // open datepicker dialog. 
            // set date picker for current date 
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
            dpd=new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                //Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-19 
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate((current_year-16-1970)*MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate((current_year-100-1970)*MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR);
            }
            return dpd;
        }
        return null;
        }

    public void setDate() {
        /*
         * Initialise Listener for date set
         */
        txtdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
                .append(day));

        datePickerOnDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                txtdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                        .append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-")
                        .append(dayOfMonth));
            }


        };

        // initialise DatePicker 

        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        intCurrentYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        intCurrentMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        intCurrentDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        intMaxYear =  intCurrentYear-18;
        intMaxMonth = intCurrentMonth;
        intMaxDay =  intCurrentDay;

        intMinYear =  intCurrentYear-100;
        intMinMonth = intCurrentMonth;
        intMinDay =  intCurrentDay; 

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange(
               this, datePickerOnDateSetListener,intMinYear,intMinMonth,intMinDay,intMaxYear,intMaxMonth,intMaxDay);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date 
            txtdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

           }
        };

}
```

The custom class for versions prior to honeycomb:

```
package com.example.datepickercustom;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange extends DatePickerDialog {

     static int maxYear=2005; 
     static int maxMonth=11;
     static int maxDay=31;

     int minYear=1955;
     int minMonth=0;
     int minDay=1;


    public DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange(Context context,  OnDateSetListener callBack,int minYear,int minMonth,int minDay,int maxYear,int maxMonth,int maxDay) {
        super(context,callBack, maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
        this.minDay = minDay;
        this.minMonth = minMonth;
        this.minYear = minYear;
        DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxDay = maxDay;
        DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxMonth = maxMonth;
        DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxYear = maxYear;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super.onDateChanged(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            if (year > maxYear ||monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear||
                     dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth){
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
                }else if(year < minYear ||monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear||
                     dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth){
                 view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay );
                }
    }
}
```

My question is that the above appears long and hard for setting date of birth.Is there a better of doing the above?

Answer (score 0):

`DatePicker` has [setMinDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) and [setMaxDate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long)) methods. It's very easy to set minimum and maximum dates with them.

What do you mean under this?:

> versions prior to honeycomb work differently from versions after
>   honeycomb

Of cause there's difference. `DatePicker` matches current Android version and there **should** be difference as well as for any control.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party libraries for presenting a calendar view and then on click you can choose the desired date.I have used the time square lib for same purpose and is very nice.take a look [HERE](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/01/times-square.html).
There is another good library check [THIS](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)
use them in a dialog and cancel the dialog when you are done picking the date.As mentioned you can also show the view within any date range you want.So you can set a max and min date.Just have to read the usage properly and its easy and effective